# Google Speech-To-Text returning an empty response when using the python client library

Tags: python, jquery, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am trying to utilise the google Speech-To-Text python client library. My requests hit the api fine but the response is empty. I am using audio binary data sent from the client. The microphone input is recorded for 3 seconds and then sent via an ajx request.

I've tried altering the encode, changing it to base64 but nothing seems to provide successful response.

Here's my python code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import io
import os
import sys
import json
import base64

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/audio', methods=['PUT'])
def audio():
    client = speech.SpeechClient()
    content = request.files['audio'].read()
    # with open('voice.wav', 'wb') as file:
    #   file.write(content)
    # with open('voice.wav', 'rb') as file:
    #   content = file.read();
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=base64.b64encode(content))
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=48000,
        language_code='en-US')

    # Detects speech in the audio file
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
    print(response, file=sys.stderr)

    for result in response.results:
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript), file=sys.stderr)

    return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

And my js code

```
const recordAudio = () =>
new Promise(async resolve => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  const audioChunks = [];

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data);
  });

  const start = () => mediaRecorder.start();

  const stop = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      const play = () => audio.play();
      resolve({ audioBlob, audioUrl, play });
    });

    mediaRecorder.stop();
  });

  resolve({ start, stop });
});

const sendAudio = (audioBlob) =>
new Promise(async resolve => {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('audio', audioBlob, 'audio')
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: '/audio',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  }).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 });
})

const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

const handleAction = async () => {
  const recorder = await recordAudio();
  const actionButton = document.getElementById('action');
  actionButton.disabled = true;
  recorder.start();
  await sleep(3000);
  const audio = await recorder.stop();
  audio.play();
  await sendAudio(audio.audioBlob)
  await sleep(3000);
  actionButton
```

and the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Record Audio Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Audio Recording Test</h1>
    <p>Talk for 3 seconds, then you will hear your recording played back</p>
    <script src="/static/index.js"></script>
    <button id="action" onclick="handleAction()">Start recording...</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When Speech-to-Text returns an empty response, it's likely that the audio is not using the proper encoding. Make sure that the audio encoding of your data such as 'sample_rate_hertz' matches the parameters you sent in InitialRecognizeRequest.

For example, if your request specified "encoding":"FLAC" and "sampleRateHertz":16000, the audio data parameters listed by the SoX play command should be the same.

More information about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting#returns_an_empty_response).